# Вопрос по Dagger2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger2, dagger

Недавно начал изучение Dagger2 и у меня возник вопрос:
У меня есть кастомный класс PrefManager:

```
class PrefManager @Inject constructor(
    internal val preferences: SharedPreferences
) {

}
```

Далее, есть модуль, который предоставляет необходимые зависимости от SharedPreferences.

```
@Module
class LocalDataModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideSharedPreferences(context: Context): SharedPreferences =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideCustomPrefManager(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences) =
        PrefManager(sharedPreferences)
    }
}
```

Но, я также хочу предоставлять зависимости от PrefManager, для чего и написал функцию provideCustomPrefManager.

Далее этот модуль запихивается в @Component.

Хотел бы узнать, правильно ли я сделал, и, если нет, то хотел бы услышать совет/увидеть код, как было бы правильно.

Answer (score 2):

`@Provides` метод `provideCustomPrefManager` не нужен, ведь у класса уже есть `@Inject`, скоуп можно и на класс повесить

```
@Singleton 
class PrefManager @Inject constructor(...
```